# Microsoft Groups Graph API Multi-Geo: Is there a way to create groups in a specify Geo location with Application Permissions (AAD app)

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a requirement to auto provision O365 groups in desired Geo location (i.e CAN, Default being EU), I'm using AAD app permissions to authenticate to Graph API. Need help in achieving this.

I'm aware that the teams created using delegated permission will be created in the regions specific to the delegated user and found the "preferredDataLocation" property of the graph group type is updated as that of the user.

I tried creating group with this property set to desired location code(i.e CAN) with application permission and I get the below error.

Request Body:

```
  {
      "description": "Muti-Geo Graph API",
      "displayName": "Teams Multi-Geo Graph API",
      "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
      ],
      "mailEnabled": true,
      "mailNickname": "TeamsMultiGeoGraphAPI",
      "securityEnabled": false,
      "owners@odata.bind": [
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXXXX"
      ],
      "preferredDataLocation":"CAN"
    }
```

Response:

```
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "The requesting user is not authorized to set group preferred data location."
```

Please let me know if there is any way I can create O365 groups in desired geo location.

Note: Multi-Geo is enabled and CAN region is available in the tenant.

Comment: What scopes have you requested?

Comment: resource=https://graph.microsoft.com; Scope: Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` to the list of permissions of my Azure AD App solved the issue.
Here are the list of the required permissions to perform this API call:

```
Group.Create, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

Documentation: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).